# ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have following problem: I try to get the values of "place" with ngfor.
Following i use:

```
.html
<ng-container *ngFor="let se of List"
```

Following Json:

```
.json
 "place": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Ort",
      "number": "Nummer",
      "type": "Art",
      "height": 20,
      "width": 42,
      "lagerin": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "secnname": "Regal  ",
          "secnnumber": "R1",
          "sectype": {
            "sectypename": "Big ",
            "ro": 5,
            "co": 2,
            "secheight": 20,
            "secwidth": 6,
            "secdepth": 1,
            "sectco": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "secnname": "Reg 2 ",
          "secnnumber": "R2",
          "sectype": {
            "sectypename": "Small",
            "ro": 3,
            "co": 3,
            "secheight": 25,
            "secwidth": 4,
            "secdepth": 2,
            "sectco": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I get the error above. So my idea is to get the attributes in "place" to use them in my code.
It was working fine, before i add "lagerin". But i need this one in "place".

```
.ts
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params.id;
      });
    if (this.id) {
      this.service.gelager(this.id).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
          this.List= data;
        } else {
          console.log('No lager available');
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your *getLager* method returns the Json you showed us then you should have

```
this.list = data.place
```

And your local variables should not start with a capital letter, it is just a convention

Comment: thank you very much:) do you maybe know what the endpoint is of lagerin? So that i can push data into it.